# MySQL filtering

Tags: mysql, join, filter

There's this `users` table:

```
user_id     name
...         ...
```

Then there's `projects` table:

```
project_id     created_by    title
...            ...           ...
```

And `project_users` table (which connects a user to a project):

```
project_id    user_id
...           ...
```

And the SQL:

```
SELECT 
    projects.id 
FROM 
    projects 
INNER JOIN project_users 
    ON project_users.project_id = projects.id 
    AND project_users.user_id = 10
```

This selectes all the projects that has the user with `user_id = 10` attached to them.
The question is, how do I select the projects that have the user with `user_id = 10` attached to them AND is created by the user with `user_id = 10` (thru the `projects.created_by` column)?

So, if the first SQL mentioned here would return 5 projects, unless a user is attached to the projects he created, there should be 6 ore more projects returned (if he did create any).

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all projects assigned to user 10 PLUS projects that he created, you need to use OR, not AND. Also you need to use LEFT JOIN, if the user/project connection is not made for project author.

I would do it like this probably:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT projects.id 
FROM 
    projects 
LEFT JOIN project_users 
    ON project_users.project_id = projects.id 
WHERE project_users.user_id = 10 OR project.created_by = 10
```

Comment: You basically put the `AND` of the `JOIN` in the `WHERE` statement and added an extra `OR`?

Comment: This returns the project twice when the user is assigned to it and has created it. EDIT: adding a `GROUP BY` resolved this. Let me check on the real thing.

Comment: I need to group them as `WHERE ( project_users.user_id = 10 OR project.created_by = 1 ) AND ...` in case there're extra filters. Please add the `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to the answer. @MartinAdamek